# Backbone and Smart Time ago are not functioning together, any ideas?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am using backbone and:
https://github.com/pragmaticly/smart-time-ago

When I load the page there is nothing displayed where the time ago is supposed to be(but backbone is working).

Here is my backbone view:

```
class Voice.Views.PostsIndex extends Backbone.View

        template: JST['posts/index']

        initialize: ->
                @collection.on('reset', @render, this)

        render: ->
                $(@el).html(@template(posts: @collection)).timeago
                this
```

### templates/posts/index.jst.eco

```
<% for post in @posts.models: %>
        <tbody id="postdata"><tr><td>
                <center>
                <% if post.get('content').length > 140: %>
                        <%=post.get('content').substring(0, 140)+"\t\t"%>
                        ...<a href="show/<%= post.get('id') %>">see more</a>
                <% else: %>
                        <%= post.get('content') %>
                <% end %>
        <br>    </center>
        <span class="green pull-left"><%= post.get('agrees') %>&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="red pull-left"><%= post.get('disagrees') %>&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="blue pull-left">0</span>
        <span class="pull-right">
            <time class="timeago" datetime="<%=post.get('created_at')%>">
            </time>
        </span>
        </td></tr></tbody>
```

### application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require timeago
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require voice
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./collections
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./routers
//= require_tree .
```

Is there anyway to get this to work? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a function call:

```
$(@el).html(@template(posts: @collection)).timeago
```

That just looks up the `timeago` function on a jQuery object and, well, does nothing with it. You need to add parentheses (or an argument) to call `timeago`:

```
$(@el).html(@template(posts: @collection)).timeago()
# you need these ---------------------------------^^
```

If you were supplying some arguments, you wouldn't need the parentheses:

```
$(@el).html(@template(posts: @collection)).timeago selector: '.pancakes'
```

The presence of arguments is enough to tell CoffeeScript that you want to execute the function rather than get a reference to it.

Comment: Okay, I changed that but there is still no time ago being displayed.

Comment: @jquadrin: Should work fine (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/JCGG2/), is your template producing the HTML you're expecting it to?

Comment: You're correct it is working, I missed it because it took about 10 seconds to load. Is there anyway to speed this up?

Comment: I don't know, maybe play with the `selector` option like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/JCGG2/1/

Comment: is the only way to solve my timing problem is by calling .timeago() on each post separately during each single posts creation? (Just re-configuring backbone to add one post at a time instead of fetching the whole collection at once)

Comment: @jquadrin: Maybe, limiting the scope that it has to mess around with might work. I'd probably check the source to see what it is doing that is taking so much time; but, I don't use timeago, I ended up writing my own humanizer last time I needed one.